# Question on cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159136/gross-zagier-formulae-outside-of-number-theory) asserts that if we have a surface $M$, the diagonal $D \subseteq M\times M$ determines a cohomology class on $M \times M$. I'm trying to understand cohomology in general, and I understand the definition of cohomology but not exactly of how the diagonal determines a cohomology class.

How, rigorously, does cohomology stem from the diagonal of a surface?

Comment: Here $M$ is closed oriented. The diagonal represents a homology class whose Poincare dual is the cohomology class you are asking about.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek How does the diagonal represent a homology class?

Comment: It is the image of the fundamental class of $M$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_class, under the diagonal map into $M\times M$. I also suggest reading about homology say at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics) because you do not seem to know what it is.

Comment: Besides the definition of homology and cohomology themselves, you also need to understand the definition of homology and cohomology homomorphisms that are induced by continuous maps. In this situation, the inclusion map $D \hookrightarrow M \times M$ induces a homomorphism from the homology of $D$ to the homology of $M \times M$.

Comment: In the question that you linked to, $M$ is an arbitrary compact Riemannian manifold.  However, in your question, you say that $M$ is a surface (ie of real dimension two).  You should clarify whether you are really only interested in that special case.